# Who first discovered that the torus supports a flat structure?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, euclidean-geometry, math-history

Who first recognized that there exists a homogenous metric on the closed genus 1 orientable surface?

Comment: IDK. May be whoever had a sheet of paper, and noticed that you can roll it to form a tube without stretching. And then observed that if the material does stretch a bit, you could bend it to form a torus? Or may be a map-maker during a coffee break, who noticed that longitudes and latitudes would work very well on the surface of a donut. I really think that this metric on the torus is so natural that nobody would want his/her name associated with its discovery - and/or it was independently arrived at by very many people.

Answer (score 6):

I believe from [this paper](http://www.boma.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/data/42print.pdf) that Clifford was the one of the first people to describe a flat metric on the torus; he was the first to explicitly embed the torus into $\mathbb{R}^4$ in the standard flat way; this paper also states that he was one of the first to speak of the torus as a parallelogram with opposite edges identified. It's a fun paper to read!